ignore argparse generated help and usage messages and issues errors when users give the program invalid arguments
Let s assume I have a parser:
import argparse
def int_main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
    parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
    parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    int_main()

Assuming the Python code above is saved into a file called prog.py. If I give it wrong arguments in the command line:
python prog.py a b c


It gives this error message:
usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
prog.py: error: argument N: invalid int value: 'a'

In a context of mine, I don't want that error message to be generated, I want for example int_main() simply to return False if any error raised indicating parsing errors.
How to do that?
I tried :
import argparse
def int_main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
    parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
    parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
        # print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
    except:
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = int_main()
    print(res)


but didn't work.
Update
There is a bug it seems:
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)
try:
    parser.parse_args('invalid arguments'.split())
except argparse.ArgumentError:
    print('ArgumentError caught.')

still exists on error even when set to False, how to fix this? I really want a solution to cover all possible exceptions and never outputs errors, this is because I am doing some unit testing and this can break things
update2
import argparse

def copy_(name1, name2):
    return True

def int_main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='blabla',
                    exit_on_error=False,
                    argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS,
                    add_help=False)

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="subparser_name", help="")
    one_parser = subparsers.add_parser("copy_", help="")
    one_parser.add_argument(
        dest = "name1",
        type = str,
        metavar = "NAME1",
    )
    one_parser.add_argument(
        dest = "name2",
        type = str,
        metavar = "NAME2",
    )
    one_parser.set_defaults(func=copy_)

    try:
        args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args.func(args.name1, args.name2))
    except (SystemExit, SystemError, argparse.ArgumentError): 
        return False
    
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    int_main()

This one still outputs:
usage: blabla copy_ [-h] NAME1 NAME2
blabla copy_: error: the following arguments are required: NAME2

when submitting this command python arg.py copy_ a. How can we see only False and not the error message?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error

The docs also talk about customizing the error and exit methods.  The default for most errors is to display usage and error, and then do a system exit.

@hpaulj Yes, but I am lost really there. I did an update though to my original question

What error did you get?  Depending on the python version, exit_on_error only catches some types of errors.  argparse for its own unit testing, generally catches errors with sys.exit try.  Unit testing of argparse code is a bit tricky, but has been discussed in a number of SO.

@hpaulj Thanks, that s what I saw reading some github pages, I provided a second update and I hope I can find a solution to that one, it s reproducible.

Checking for missing arguments does not generate an ArgumentError, so it goes through error and exit.  The usage and error you see are sent to stderr.  Either you use your own versions of these two methods, or as the test_argparse.py file does, redirect stderr.  There's been talk on the argparse github issues about broadening the coverage of exit_on_error, but I don't know the status of the proposed PR.

Modifying your int_main to take an argv parameter which is then passed to parser.parse_args(argv), and
redefining the error method as
In [32]: def myerror(self, message):
    ...:     print('message:', message)
    ...:     print('no usage') # self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
    ...:     self.exit(2)
    ...:     #args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
    ...:     #self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
    ...:     

In [33]: argparse.ArgumentParser.error = myerror

Your test case produces:
In [34]: int_main('copy_ a'.split())
message: the following arguments are required: NAME2
no usage
Out[34]: False

and other errors caught by ArgumentError:
In [35]: int_main(None)
Out[35]: False

In [36]: int_main('copy_ a b'.split())
True
Out[36]: True

In [37]: int_main('foobar a b'.split())
Out[37]: False

This a crude error replacement, but gives an idea of what might be done.
For unit testing I suspect redirecting stderr would better than customizing the argparse method.  Be careful about blindly capturing errors.  It could hide some serious or unexpected flaws.
Removing the exit_on_error=False, produces the following 'error' displays:
In [40]: int_main('copy_ a b'.split())
True
Out[40]: True

In [41]: int_main(None)
message: argument subparser_name: invalid choice: 'C:\\Users\\14256\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-1783dfcfeed2.json' (choose from 'copy_')
no usage
Out[41]: False

In [42]: int_main('foobar a b'.split())
message: argument subparser_name: invalid choice: 'foobar' (choose from 'copy_')
no usage
Out[42]: False

In [43]: int_main('copy_ a b c'.split())
message: unrecognized arguments: c
no usage
Out[43]: False


Can we turn def myerror(self, message): into a class and then make an obj out of it?

What I've shown is a monkey-patch suitable for testing - though I don't have a whole lot of experience wtih unittesting.  For a more production version, you could subclass ArgumentParser, and replace the error method.

For error_on_exit to be effective, the parser has to be configured. This is enough:
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
try:
    parser.parse_args('invalid arguments'.split())
except argparse.ArgumentError:
    print('ArgumentError caught.')

giving as expected:
ArgumentError caught.


I provided a second update where I still get an error.,
